# Linearity of Expected Value: Number of Segments

Tags: probability

I have a 4x4 grid of squares.  For each individual square, a coin is tossed.  If the coin is heads, the square is stamped in blue.  There are 16 maximum stamps possible.  What is the expected number of line segments that are colored in blue?  The grid in the image shows three stamps with 10 line segments colored blue.

[image]

Since this is a binomial random variable, where each square represents an independent trial, the expected value for each square is:

$E(x) = np$

In this case n = 16, the total number of squares and p = 0.5.  The expected value for the number of squares then is :

$E(x) = 16*0.5 = 8$

Now, to find the expected value for the number of line segments, could I use the same equation?  Since there are 40 total possible line segments, n = 40.  Would p still equal 0.5 for each line segment?  If not, how would I go about calculating the probability for each line segment?

Using n = 40, and p = 0.5 for the expected number of segments:

$E(x) = 40 * 0.5 = 20$

Intuitively, it doesn't seem correct.

Comment: You have to consider two types of segments, those on the boundary and the rest ones. For segment on the boundary, it belongs only one square, hence is colored blue iff the square it belongs to is colored. For the rest segment, it belongs to two squares, each one get colored will cause this segment colored blue.

Comment: Okay, makes sense.  So the probability of a line segment along the boundary is 0.5, while the probability for the rest of the line segments is 0.75.  This is because the probability of a line segment belonging to one square is 0.5 and the probability the same line segment belongs to an adjacent square is 0.5*0.5 = 0.25?